# How to deny write servicePrincipalName for domain account in active directory

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I can't remove write servicePrincipalName property from domain account. Something is wrong with System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule which I cannot understand. Could someone help me understand the issue?

I used the following code:

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$Username = "test_user"
$SPNProperty = "servicePrincipalName" 
# Get the security descriptor for the user object
$SD = (Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties nTSecurityDescriptor).nTSecurityDescriptor 
# Get the GUID of the servicePrincipalName attribute
$SPNSchemaObj = Get-ADObject -SearchBase ((Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext) -Filter { LDAPDisplayName -eq $SPNProperty } -Properties schemaIDGUID
$SPNSchemaID = $SPNSchemaObj.schemaIDGUI
# Create a new access rule to deny the "Write Property" permission for the servicePrincipalName attribute
$AccessRule = (New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule -ArgumentList $Username, "WriteProperty", "Deny",$SPNSchemaID) 
# Add the new access rule to the security descriptor
$SD.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule) 
# Set the modified security descriptor on the user object
Set-ADUser -Identity $Username -Replace @{nTSecurityDescriptor = $SD}
```

I get the following error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "ActiveDirectoryAccessRule" and the argument count: "6".
At line:10 char:16
+ ... cessRule = (New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccess ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:14 char:1
+ $SD.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccessRule($AccessRule)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Answer (score 0):

`$SPNSchemaObj.schemaIDGUI` should have a `D` on the end.

`schemaIDGUID` needs to be converted from bytes like:

```
$SPNSchemaID = $SPNSchemaObj.schemaIDGUID -as [guid]
```

Your `ActiveDirectoryAccessRule` is missing parameters. Take a look at the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964424/how-can-i-lookup-an-active-directory-classs-schema-id-guid-and-an-attributes), or the other constructors [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryaccessrule.-ctor):

```
$ace = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule]::New($identity, $adRights, $type, $objectType, $inheritanceType, $inheritedObjectType)
```